# Can I have a TreeView action that doesn't show up in the command palette?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I want to have a TreeView in my VS Code extension, and I want to be able to right-click on items in the view and have a context menu with actions in it. The [official way to do this](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/tree-view#view-actions) is to add it to the `menus` object of the manifest:

```
"view/item/context": [
      {
        "command": "myExtension.myAction",
        "when": "view == myExtension",
        "group": "inline"
      }
]
```

The command `myExtension.myAction` now (as far as I can tell) has to be added to the `commands` section of the manifest. **This causes it to show up in the command palette.** This is very inconvenient. My contextual action is meaningless outside of the context of right-clicking on an item, it would just clutter up the command palette.

Is there any way of hooking view actions up with commands *without* having them show up in the command palette?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my testing (by no means absolutely thorough) it also works, more simply, to add this enablement clause to your commands:

```
"contributes": {
    "commands": [
        {
            "command": "myExtension.myAction",
            "when": "view == myExtension",
            "enablement": "view == <your treeview id here>"
            "group": "inline"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I do that the command doesn't show in the Command Palette for me.  And then you don't need the `commandPalette` menu entry.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the most intuitive thing in the world, but it's pretty simple. First, as mentioned in the answer, you must list your command in the `commands` section of the extension manifest (`package.json`):

```
"contributes": {
    "commands": [
        {
            "command": "myExtension.myAction",
            "when": "view == myExtension",
            "group": "inline"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, in the `menus` section of your `contributes`, set the `when` expression for the command to false:

```
"contributes": {
    "menus": {
        "commandPalette": [
            {
                "command": "myExtension.myAction",
                "when": "false"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The when expression controls when the command should show up in the command palette, so this means it will be absent permanently. See [the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/command#controlling-when-a-command-shows-up-in-the-command-palette).